# Convert a text list to numbers?

Tags: python, list, text

I am trying to use `float()` to convert the following list to numbers. But it always says `ValueError: could not convert string to float`.

I understand that this error occurs when there is something in text that cannot be treated as a number. But my list seems okay.

```
a = ['4', '4', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '4', '8', '16', '3', '9', '27', '81', '4', '16', '64', '256', '4', '3']

b = [float(x) for x in a]
```

Comment: I'm assuming `a` is your list, this code snippet works for me so you need to post complete code that others can run to reproduce your error

Comment: print out 'a' in your interpreter, it should have already been defined to a string.

Comment: what does `set(map(type,a))` say?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['4', '4', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '4', '8', '16', '3', '9', '27', '81', '4', '16', '64', '256', '4', '3']

b = [float(x) for x in a]
```

Works perfectly.

```
['4', '4', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '4', '8', '16', '3', '9', '27', '81', '4', '16', '64', '256', '4', '3']

b = [float(x) for x in a]
```

Not so much.

Your error message shows that one of you entries is a single quotation mark or an empty element in your list. For example,

```
a = ['the', '4', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '4', '8', '16', '3', '9', '27', '81', '4', '16', '64', '256', '4', '3']

b = [float(x) for x in a]
```

throws the error:
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: the`

Comment: Sorry my bad. Actually the list was taken from a txt file as follows: f=open('mytext.txt','r') a=f.read().split()

Comment: I found that if I do split() separately, it will cause parsing problem as I mentioned. But if I just run a=f.read().split(), no problem... I got confused.

Comment: If you still need assistance, edit your question please.

Answer (score 0):

The list you have posted is perfectly ok with your method.

- Either you have `a` already define to a string and don't have a pointed to that list.
- The list contains a number.

Just to verify try

```
map(int,a) #if no errors you have all numbers
```

Then try

```
set(map(type,a)) #if outputs {str} you should be good.
```

Either way your error is not reproducible and post more details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what the Traceback log says: Could not convert string to float

1. If you have a string with only numbers, python's smart enough to do what you're trying and converts the string to a float.
2. If you have a string with non-numerical characters, the conversion will fail and give you the error that you were having.

You can strip whitespaces and then check for digits in the string.

```
 f = open('mytext.txt','r') 
 a = f.read().split()
 a = [each.strip() for each in a]
 a = [each for each in a if each.isdigit() ]
 b = [float(each) for each in a]  # or b = map(float, a)
 print b
 # just to make it clear written as separate steps, you can combine the steps
```

Answer (score -1):

you can convert list using

if you have any string in your list then you get error message 
`ValueError: could not convert string to float` like that

```
>>> a = ['4', '4', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '4', '8', '16', '3', '9', '27', '81', '4', '16', '64', '256', '4', '3']
>>> b = list(map(float, a))
>>> b
```

output

```
[4.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 8.0, 16.0, 3.0, 9.0, 27.0, 81.0, 4.0, 16.0, 64.0, 256.0, 4.0, 3.0]
```